# Custom Lambda layer for Kronecker product in Keras - troubles with the dimension reserved for batch_size

Tags: python, tensorflow, lambda, keras, keras-layer

I am using Keras 2.1.5 with Tensorflow backend to create a model for image classification.
In my model, I would like to combine the input and the output of a convolution layer by counting the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). I've written the functions which counts the Kronecker product of two 3D tensors using the Keras backend functions.

```
def kronecker_product(mat1, mat2):
    #Computes the Kronecker product of two matrices.
    m1, n1 = mat1.get_shape().as_list()
    mat1_rsh = K.reshape(mat1, [m1, 1, n1, 1])
    m2, n2 = mat2.get_shape().as_list()
    mat2_rsh = K.reshape(mat2, [1, m2, 1, n2])
    return K.reshape(mat1_rsh * mat2_rsh, [m1 * m2, n1 * n2])

def kronecker_product3D(tensors):
    tensor1 = tensors[0]
    tensor2 = tensors[1]
    #Separete slices of tensor and computes appropriate matrice kronecker product
    m1, n1, o1 = tensor1.get_shape().as_list()
    m2, n2, o2 = tensor2.get_shape().as_list()
    x_list = []
    for ind1 in range(o1):
        for ind2 in range(o2):
            x_list.append(DenseNetKTC.kronecker_product(tensor1[:,:,ind1], tensor2[:,:,ind2]))
    return K.reshape(Concatenate()(x_list), [m1 * m2, n1 * n2, o1 * o2])
```

Then I've tried to use the Lambda layer to wrap the operation into Keras layer:

```
cb = Convolution2D(12, (3,3), padding='same')(x)
x = Lambda(kronecker_product3D)([x, cb])
```

but received the error "*ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)*". I expect the input to be the tensor of 3 dimensions, but in fact, it has 4 dimensions - the first dimension reserved for the batch_size in Keras. I do not know how to deal with this fourth dimension with dynamic size.

I've searched a lot, but cannot find any example function which deals manualy with the dimension for batches.

I would be glad for any tips or help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Easy solution:**

Simply add the batch dimension to your calcs and reshapes

```
def kronecker_product(mat1, mat2):
    #Computes the Kronecker product of two matrices.
    batch, m1, n1 = mat1.get_shape().as_list()
    mat1_rsh = K.reshape(mat1, [-1, m1, 1, n1, 1])
    batch, m2, n2 = mat2.get_shape().as_list()
    mat2_rsh = K.reshape(mat2, [-1, 1, m2, 1, n2])
    return K.reshape(mat1_rsh * mat2_rsh, [-1, m1 * m2, n1 * n2])

def kronecker_product3D(tensors):
    tensor1 = tensors[0]
    tensor2 = tensors[1]
    #Separete slices of tensor and computes appropriate matrice kronecker product
    batch, m1, n1, o1 = tensor1.get_shape().as_list()
    batch, m2, n2, o2 = tensor2.get_shape().as_list()
    x_list = []
    for ind1 in range(o1):
        for ind2 in range(o2):
            x_list.append(kronecker_product(tensor1[:,:,:,ind1], tensor2[:,:,:,ind2]))
    return K.reshape(Concatenate()(x_list), [-1, m1 * m2, n1 * n2, o1 * o2])
```

For the hard solution, I would try to figure out a way to avoid iterating, but that may be way more complex than I thought....

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works when I try it on a small example. Unfortunately, when I tried to build the model in Keras whit this lambda function it takes a long time and then it is killed. Probably I run out of memory or something... I will try it on a more powerful machine...
I would be way better without the for loops, but this solution seems to be out of my imagination...

Comment: Yes, you've got squared data size there.

Comment: I need to do more operation on each tensor in the batch, is there some possibility to somehow loop over the tensors in the batch? My idea is to count the Kronecker product and consequently do some transformation/compression to make the output the original size once again. I found some discussions where they recommend to use keras.backend.rnn or tensorflow.scan function as equivalent to loop, but I did not find any concrete example with implementation.